# cell.contentView.viewWithTag not working in static tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to get access to a `UIImageView`from my cell in a static tableView, I use a `UITableViewController`within a `ContainerView`witch is embedded in my `ViewController`, here is my code :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath 
     indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    println(cell.contentView.viewWithTag(10))
    if indexPath.row ==  self.selectedCellInIndex {
        cell.contentView.viewWithTag(10)?.hidden = false


    }
    else {
    cell.contentView.viewWithTag(10)?.hidden = true
    }
    return cell
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.selectedCellInIndex = indexPath.row
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

but always `cell.contentView.viewWithTag(10)`is returning nil and when I do : `println("cell.contentView.subviews.count)` I get 0, I tried : `cell.viewWithTag(10)` and the same problem retain,I searched a lot even in other questions dealing with this issue but I didn't find any solution that works for me, how can I fix it ?

Comment: which xcode version you are using

Comment: I'm using xcode6.1, I found the solution, it's strange but it fixed the issue, I unchecked Size classes, clean and build and recheck Size classes option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it's strange but it fixed the issue:

1. I unchecked Size classes
2. clean and build and
3. recheck Size classes option

Answer (score 0):

With static cells you can create IBOutlet just by control dragging the item to the view controller source file and avoid the viewWithTag.

Comment: I want to uses viewWith tag because I have many images and I want to ovoid creating an IBOutlet for each of them